# Pad power does not correlate with each other in altium

Tags: pcb, altium, routing

I'm working on a project in Altium. When I want to route the PCB, I have a problem that the ground pad are not showing the lines in order to connect it.  Also pad +3V have the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your schematic? Did you validate your project? (Right click on project name and check messages tab in lower right menu)

Comment: Maybe they're hidden (N, S, A; or D, N, N, select and edit net; or list nets in the List panel/dialog and edit it there, etc.)

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, it worked for me. It was hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show hidden nets: N, S, A; or D, N, N, select and edit net; or list nets in the List panel/dialog and edit it there, etc.  They could also be set to poorly visible colors, which can be found editing the net objects.

Tim